# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'? The thing is, my two variables are int

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

I'm a benginner, so this might be a very easy mistake, yet it got me.

I get "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'" when I try to compare len(Conjunto) <= N-1, in a while cycle.

> Blockquote< N = int(input("Ingrese n : "))
>                       while len(Conjunto)<=N-1:>

I don't understand what am I doing wrong, here's my code, where you can see that both len(Conjunto) and N are int.

```
from math import factorial
class Permutacion:
    P3=""

    def SinR(self):
        P4=""
        N=0
        OK = False
        Conjunto = []
        Cont=1
        Add=None 
        while OK==False:
              try:
                    N = int(input("Ingrese n : "))
                    while len(Conjunto)<=N-1:
                       Add = input("Ingrese el Elemento N\xfamero "+str(Cont)+" : ")
                       if Add in Conjunto:
                           print("El elemento no puede repetise")
                       else:
                           Conjunto.append(Add)
                           Cont+=1
                    while True:
                           P4 = input("\xbfSe Identifica al Primer Elemento? (Y/N)")
                           P4 = P4.upper()
                           if P4=="Y" or P4=="N":
                               break
                    if P4=="N":
                        N=(N-1)
                    N = factorial(N)
                    N = str(N)
                    print("Hay " +N+" Posibles Permutaciones sin Repetici\xf3n")
                    OK=True
              except:
                    print("Ha ocurrido un error   :(")
                    print("\xbfSegugo de que has introducido un n\xfamero?")
              return N


    def ConR(self):
     Conjunto = ["A"]
     Dict = {"A":1}
     Cont = 1
     Aux=None
     AUX=None
     Add = None
     OK=False
     N=0
     while OK == False:
        #try:
            N = int( input("Ingrese n : ") )
            while len(Conjunto)<=N-1:
                    Add = input("Ingrese el Elemento N\xfamero " + str(Cont) + " : ")
                    if Add in Conjunto:
                                Aux = Dict.get(Add)
                                AUX = Aux + 1
                                Dict.update({Add:AUX})
                                print(Dict)
                                Conjunto.append(Add)
                                Cont+=1
                    else:
                        Conjunto.append(Add)
                        Dict.update({Add:1})
                        Cont+=1
                    N = factorial(N)
                    N = str(N)
                    print("Hay " + N + " Posibles Permutaciones con Repetici\xf3n")
                    OK = True
        #except:
            print("Ha ocurrido un error   :(")
            print("\xbfSegugo de que has introducido un n\xfamero?")
     return N



    def Asignar(self):
        while True:
              P3 = input("\xbfSe Repite Alg\xfan Elemento? (Y/N) : ")
              P3 = P3.upper()
              if P3 == "N":
                  Permutacion.SinR(self)
                  break
              elif P3 == "Y":
                  Permutacion.ConR(self)
                  break
              else:
                  print("Por favor, presione 'Y' o 'N'")













#class Combinacion
#class Variacion
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:                                          
        P1 = "X"
        P2 = "X"
        while P1 != "Y" and P1 != "N":
            print("  ")
            print("Programa Que Ejecuta T\xe9cnicas de Conteo")
            P1 = input("\xbfImporta el Orden? (Y/N) : ")
            P1 = P1.upper()
            if P1 == "Y":
                while P2 != "Y" and P2 != "N":
                    P2=input("\xbfSe Toman Todos los Elementos? (Y/N) : ")
                    P2=P2.upper()
                    if P2 == "Y": 
                        print("Permutaci\xf3n")
                        Per = Permutacion()
                        Per.Asignar()
                    elif P2 == "N":
                         print("Variaci\xf3n")
                         #Variacion()
                    break
            elif P1 =="N":
                print("Combinaci\xf3n")
                #Combinacion()
```

Comment: What is your input to reproduce your error?

Answer (score 1):

Variable N in your program should be integer, if you want to use it in expression (N-1).
But after factorial calculation you cast it to str:

```
N = factorial(N)
N = str(N)
print("Hay " + N + " Posibles Permutaciones con Repetici\xf3n")
```

Do not change type of N, just provide print function with string, like that:

```
N = factorial(N)
print("Hay " + str(N) + " Posibles Permutaciones con Repetici\xf3n")
```

Or, better, use .format():

```
N = factorial(N)
print("Hay {Number} Posibles Permutaciones con Repetici\xf3n".format(Number=N))
```

Comment: I tried that, and I get a similar syntax error.                                                             while len(Conjunto)<=M-1:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax           I have no idea what am I doing wrong!

Comment: Please explain, where did you get SyntaxError?